# Ruby on rails: How to run a background task automatically when the server starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have created a rails application that runs a background process. It pings a server periodically and displays a graph for the response time. For this I am using a gem called crono. I am starting the task from the command line using 'bundle exec crono'.

How can I run the background process automatically when the rails server starts without having to start it from the command line?

Also, is there a way to automatically refresh the page periodically so that it displays an updated graph?

Edit: This application will be deployed to production.
Edit: I still couldn't get this to work. Here's the folder structure:

---

> application/config/
>       ping_job.rb
>       cronotab.rb

cronotab uses 'crono' gem to execute the task inside ping_job.rb every 5 seconds.

> require 'typhoeus'
>   class PingJob
>     def peform
>      #task definition goes here.
>     end
>   end

I want to run the task defined in ping_job.rb automatically when the server starts. I am thinking of using whenever gem. Any and all suggestions is welcome.

Comment: to start things on system startup, use your system's standard tool for this. For example, on ubuntu it used to be upstart. Now it's systemd, I think. Other systems can have other tools. Consult documentation for the tool that you have.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in config/environment.rb right under `Rails.application.initialize!`  this is ran to start up the rails server, so would be run after the application is initialized

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wanted to join the start of a background process with the start of the rail server as well as you. And in the end I found out that it is the bad idea. I think the best solution is to create a deploy task that starts and restarts the process on each deploy. For example capistrano allows to do something like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do
    invoke 'my_process:start'
  end

  task :stop do
    invoke 'my_process:stop'
  end

  task :restart do
    invoke 'my_process:start'
    invoke 'my_process:stop'
  end
end

namespace :my_process
  task :start do
    execute "some system command to start the process"
  end

  task :stop do
    execute "some system command to stop the process"
  end
end
```

Never start your process in Rails initialization files. It might start the process several times when there are few application workers on your server. Or it might start the process when you start the Rails console and so on.